# Rotating a picture in PHP once it's saved

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I have this PHP script that saves a picture on my website. I would like to, once the picture is saved, rotate the picture by 90 degrees if it's not landscape. This a piece of my script:

```
$uploadfile = 'path/where/to/save/picture.jpg';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { 
    //The code under here is not working
    if($_GET['landscape'] == false || $_GET['landscape'] == 'false'){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadfile);
        $newimg = imagerotate($img, 90.0, 0);
        imagejpeg($newimg, $uploadfile);
    }

    //this is code under here is working
    $prev = create_preview($filename, $uploadfile, $ext, true);
}
```

As you can see I move_uploaded_file() and then I have an if statement that if the picture is not landscape (so landscape == false) I rotate it. Then I create a preview of the picture.

If I comment out the if statement that checks the landscape the code WORKS, so it uploads the picture but it's NOT ROTATED as I want and creates a preview. If I let the if uncommented (like in this case) it seems like it's not saved anymore because when I try to visualize it I see nothing. This means that the code flow goes into the if, then something happens and the picture is not visualized anymore. The problem is in the if statement that rotates the picture.

So there is definitely something wrong in the procedure to rotate the picture, but I don't understand exactly what's wrong, I create the image from the location it has been uploaded to, I rotate it using the PHP function and then recreate the image in the same exact location.

Can anyone of you see where I'm getting this wrong?

Thanks,

Masiar

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['landscape']`? Also, why aren't you simply testing yourself whether the image is in portrait instead of (apparently) relying on the user to tick a checkbox?

Comment: The value of $_GET['landscape'] is false, if the picture is portrait and has to be rotated (that is, if it enters the if statement, it doesn't work). The input is not a webpage, is an iPhone application and it seems like in iPhone each picture is taken landscape (so also a portrait one is saved landscape and I have to rotate it) but I cannot manage to rotate it via Objective-C so I rather tried to rotate it through PHP which I'm more familiar with but with no success, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Is that a literal `"false"`, or a `false`, or a `0` or `null` or something else? Apparently you're not sure yourself? Try `var_dump($_GET['landscape'])`.

Comment: I'm not sure because it depends on how `%i` translates a boolean `false` in Objective-C and the point is not that because if it enters the if-statement it does something that "breaks" somehow the image, so it's not that it doesn't enter there, it's that that piece of code that should rotate the image is not working. The `$_GET['landscape']` is not important.

Comment: I thought it works if you simply comment out the `if` statement? You'll need to do a little more step by step debugging here. `var_dump` or log important values at various steps to figure out where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: No, it works means it saves the picture, but the picture is still with wrong orientation. I want the code to execute correctly the if-statement, which is not the case because when it goes inside the if, something happens and the picture not only is not rotated but it doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: Well, presumably there's an error being thrown. What happens if you enable errors? (e.g. `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script.)

Comment: [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php): *"Returns an image resource for the rotated image, or FALSE on failure."* - Actually check if you could rotate the image before you proceed. Same for saving the image. Check the return value of `imagejpeg()` before you proceed.

Comment: One thought -- is this running on a Linux box? Ubuntu or Debian? Because those distributions don't generally support `imagerotate()` in PHP out of the box due to some odd security issues with PHP's GD they don't like.

Comment: Do you think some of the functions is not properly working? Which one do you suspect? It's highly likely that these functions work, however your system can prevent files to store or you made an error in your condition to rotate the image, or there is not enough memory to rotate the picture. You need to find out all this on your own, because only you can run the script.

Comment: I'm doing the upload via iphone, I cannot see the errors returned by the PHP, do you have any suggestions on how to show them? Thanks

Comment: Anyhow I dont know why but the script now doesn't give any "error" (meaning that the picture is correctly uploaded even if it's portrait) but still it's not rotated, so maybe it's the functionality of imagerotate()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shame you can't see the error messages. I suggest writing a small test page that will "fake" the iPhone side of things and allow you to test by submitting images without using the phone. Or simply write a short script that will open an image, `imagerotate()` it and save it, and use that for testing.

Also, as gnud points out, the PHP errors may even already be being written out to a server logfile. (Typically, they'll be somewhere like `/var/log/apache/...`, but figuring out where they are on your box will be more of a question for SuperUser, I guess...)

Having said that, given all you've said, I suspect that the PHP package for the distribution of Linux you're using does not support the (fairly-heavily-edited) PHP "packaged" version of the GD library. See [this enhancement request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/39719) for Ubuntu for some details.

This means that the `imagerotate()` function that you're using simply doesn't exist. You'd verify this easily if you enabled error reporting and used a test script.

As a workaround, your options are either to find a version of the GD library that you can install on your box to replace the standard one, or perhaps [use a function written in PHP to do the rotation manually](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagerotate.php#48725).

Alternatively, as Eamorr suggests, you could shell out to a command-line tool like ImageMagick (or maybe use ImageMagick via the [PECL ImageMagick library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), but that's probably overkill for one rotate.)

As an aside, I believe the iPhone specifically "rotates" photos that it's taken (e.g. in landscape orientation) by setting a flag in the image metadata, rather than actually rotating the image data, so if you're rotating images taken on an iPhone, make sure that you test with images taken in both portrait and landscape orientations, and check that your image rotation is doing the right thing in each case.

If I recall correctly, the photo data is *always* in portrait orientation, and just has the "landscapeness" set in the EXIF orientation data if the photo was taken with the phone held in landscape orientation. There are different values for if the phone's held upside-down, too.

Comment: +1 for writing a test-page.
Also, you can log errors to a server log file.

Comment: The test page definitely was helpful. I thought about doing it but I had lack of time, fortunately I've found out an already written upload form (both html + php) and I just had to modify a little bit the server side. It turned out that imagerotate() simply doesn't exist (no GD) so I tried calling the function you pointed out and it worked! Now I have to figure out what's wrong with the communication between iPhone and PHP, but up until now thanks a lot! That particular function saved me! :)

Answer (score 1):

To flip 180 degrees:

exec('mogrify -flip /path/to/your/picture');

You need to install imagemagick

I'm sure you can figure out how to flip it 90 degrees very easily.